# Running a maven build inside a shell script for loop

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, maven-2

I have written a script that takes project names as arguments and runs a maven build on them by iterating over the arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash -xv

name=`date +%Y:%m:%d-%T`
start_time=`date +%s`
filename="log-"$name
un=`whoami`
cd "/home/"$un"/projects/buildlogs/"

`touch $filename`

filepath="/home/"$un"/projects/buildlogs/"$filename

echo "Logging to "$filepath"."
echo $@
for var in $@
    do
        path="/home/"$un"/projects/"$var
        echo $path
        cd $path
        pwd
        echo "Building "$var"."
        mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -o &>> $filepath
        mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse -o &>> $filepath
    done

end_time=date +%s
echo "Build Successful!"
echo "Execution Time: "$(($(($end_time-$start_time))/60))" mins."
```

the problem here is that the script exits before the actual build process starts and also that the output of the build process is displaying on the terminal itself in spite of my putting a redirection for the output. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: First issue: `touch $filename` does not need to be inside `\``s;
second: instead of `/home/$un` you could just write `"$HOME"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but those parts are working fine...its the build command thats giving me trouble..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Your `bash` does not recognize `&>>` redirection, so it seems that You start the processes in the background, so it is not a miracle that it exits fast. If You want to run in the background, put a `wait` after the `done` line and the script will wait until the last background process finishes.

If You want to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to the file use `someprocess args >>logfile 2>&1`.

Other comments:

- If You use `$@` it worth to put double quotation mark around (`"$@"`). Otherwise it is equals to `$*`. `"$@"` is safer as the item can contain space.
- But in this case the for-loop could be written as `for i; do` as the default args of for are the positional parameters.
- Also the ` character is pointless around `touch $filename`.
- `cd "/home/"$un"/projects/buildlogs/"` could be written as `cd ~/projects/buildlogs/`. Similar can be applied all `/home/$un` strings.
- Variable expansion can be placed inside double quotation marks. E.g. `echo "AAA $x BBB"`
- The last line could be written more simple `echo "Execution Time: $(((end_time-start_time)/60)) mins."`
- Filename could be made in one step: `filename=log-$(date +%Y:%m:%d-%T)`. Or even better: `printf -v filename "log-%(Y:%m:%d-%T)T" -1`. This does not implies the call of the external `date(1)` utility.
- Actually you do not need to go to `~/projects/buildlogs/` directory. You can use `touch $filepath` instead. But as I see, `touch` is not really important. Only in case there is no any (valid) arguments added to the command line of the script.

Comment: @Tejask06: I added some more possible simplification comments.